# IPCamera based on RA5350 CRC error on startup

Tags: disassembly, mips

I have an old IP camera that no longer works, doesn't start the `ipcamn` executable (application that also listens for port 80 connections).
Therefore I cannot access it via the network and the camera doesn't perform its intended purpose.

It is based on a RA5350 chip, if I attach a serial to USB adapter to it I can see it booting, then it outputs:

```
Data CRC 01e4cb65 != calculated CRC ed5f8089 for node at 00240af0
Data CRC 01e4cb65 != calculated CRC ed5f8089 for node at 00240af0
Data CRC 01e4cb65 != calculated CRC ed5f8089 for node at 00240af0
```

The system is usable, I can move around, I even copied the contents in search of which program outputs this error.

I have found that the camera uses two processes `videocatch` and `ipcamn` (this is true according to other internet resources as well).
The `ipcamn` is the process outputting these errors. However upon disassembling or looking at the strings contained in it or the `.so` files on the system I cannot find anything related to the error above.

I'd like to trace the error to its cause and see if it's fixable.
Any ideas?

```
# cat /proc/cpuinfo
system type             : Ralink SoC
processor               : 0
cpu model               : MIPS 24K V4.12
BogoMIPS                : 239.61
wait instruction        : yes
microsecond timers      : yes
tlb_entries             : 32
extra interrupt vector  : yes
hardware watchpoint     : yes
ASEs implemented        : mips16 dsp
VCED exceptions         : not available
VCEI exceptions         : not available
```

I also tried to rule out HW problems by copying the binaries over to a Debian MIPS system in QEMU, but I cannot run the executables on MIPS nor on MIPSEL:

```
user@debian-mips:~/mnt/bin$ ./ipcamn 
-bash: ./ipcamn: cannot execute binary file
```

```
root@debian-mipsel:/home/user/mnt/bin# ./ipcamn 
bash: ./ipcamn: No such file or directory
```

```
root@debian-mipsel:/home/user/mnt/bin# file ipcamn 
ipcamn: ELF 32-bit LSB executable, MIPS, MIPS-II version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked (uses shared libs), stripped
```

The file exists and is executable.

Comment: What about it doesn't work exactly?

Comment: The camera's `ipcamn` applicatoin doesn't start. Therefore I cannot access it since there is no web daemon running. After I get those errors on the serial port, there is no other thing that's happening on the camera..

Comment: Strage I forgot to mention this, I edited the post, thanks.

Comment: The error _"No such file or directory"_ is almost certainly due to it not being able to find the needed shared libraries or ld.